# How to Optimize Algorithm for Many Queries

Tags: algorithms

I'm approaching the following problem: Given some input array $A$ of length $n$, and integer tuple $(j,k)$, I want to determine if there exists a contiguous subarray of length $j$ with all elements greater than $k$. The $O(n)$ algorithm is straightforward, but becomes inefficient when confronting a modified version of this problem, which involves an input array A and a series of $n$ inputs $(j, k)$. How can I find an algorithm for solving this modified problem that performs strictly better than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: So $n$ is both the length of $A$ **and** the number of queries? I seem to have seen this problem in the last two days on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have a link to the post or remember the post title?

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the source?  Did you see it in a textbook/course?  In a coding contest?  If it was in a course, what topic where you studying at the time?  What approaches have you tried so far?  Have you tried to find a divide-and-conquer algorithm?